# UrlMatcher matches route with parameter when parameter does not exist (not like in the documentation)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two very simple routes (among others):

```
.state("master", {
           abstract: true,
           url: "/{tenantName}",
           ...
 })

.state("default", {
           url: "",
           ...
 })
```

This is from the documentation:

> '/user/:id' - Matches '/user/bob' or '/user/1234!!!' or even '/user/'
>   but not '/user' or '/user/bob/details'. The second path segment will
>   be captured as the parameter 'id'.

So now if I go to www.myserver.com I exect the second route to kick in, because according to documentation it should not match the direct url, but in fact it does and causes me lots of troubles. Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I want www.myserver.com go to second route and www.myserver.com/tenant1 to go to first route.

Comment: Try `.state("/master"...`.

Comment: this does not seem to help, this is just the state name, what does the "/" mean for the name?